# How to persist and reset state in Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a requirement where I need to show the aggregated count of a specific category starting from the onset of current day till current time.

I am using Structure Streaming to do the grouping. As window does not persist state of a dataframe, I am not sure how to implement the logic where I can persist its state and increment the counter on previous state. 
Also how will I reset the state on the onset of a new day.

**Input Record:**

```
{"Floor_Id" : "Shop Floor 1",
"HaltRecord" : {
    "HaltReason" : "Danahydraulic Error",
    "Severity" : "Low",
    "FaultErrorCategory" : "Docked",
    "NonFaultErrorCategory" : null
},
"Description" : "Forklift",
"Category" : {
    "Type" : "Halt",
    "End_time" : NumberLong(2018-02-13T12:00:01),
    "Start_time" : NumberLong(2018-02-13T12:00:00)
},
"Asset_Id" : 123,
"isError" : "y",
"Timestamp": 2018-02-13T12:00:01}
```

**Output Response:**

```
{
    "Floor_Id": "Shop Floor 1",
    "Error_Category": [
        {
            "Category": "Operator Error",
            "DataPoints": 
                {
                    "NumberOfErrors": 20,
                    "Date": 2018-02-13
                }
        },
        {
            "Category": "Danahydraulic Error",
            "DataPoints": {
                    "NumberOfErrors": 15,
                    "Date": 2018-02-13
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t used structured stream’s state function but I know it’s mapGroupWithState function that provide the ability to persist state and do count logic.

Comment: Yeah there's mapGroupWithState and flatMapGroupWithState but then how to implement the reset logic. As per the documentation, there can be two types of timeout configurations: Processing Based and Event Based Timeout. My requirement is such that I want to specify a particular time in the timeout configurations.

Comment: Maybe you can use the date in the key,for example,use "Shop Floor 1-2019-2-16" as the key in state,then if a new day come,the state of the new day's key "Shop Floor 1-2019-2-17" will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the state you can use `state.remove()` in the the udf called from the `mapGroupWithState` and `flatMapGroupWithState` functions after the processing is done. These functions are only available in java and Scala as of now.
If somebody knows how to implement this in python, please let me know. I have been looking for it.